Under what assumptions is the Jensen's inequality sufficient for concavity (or convexity) of a function?
We know that concave (convex) functions satisfy Jensen's inequality. But could we infer the converse under some additional assumptions, i.e. under what assumptions is Jensen's inequality is an if and only if type of result?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Jensen's inequality is already an if and only if result.
Indeed, suppose that $f$ is a function such that $f(\mathbf{E} X) \leq \mathbf{E}f(X) $ for all random variables $X$.
But then, for any $a, b$ in the domain of $f$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we can define the random variable
$$
X = \begin{cases}
a &\text{w.p. } \lambda, \\
b &\text{w.p. } 1 - \lambda,
\end{cases}
$$
so that
$$
f(\lambda a + (1 - \lambda) b)
= f(\mathbf{E} X)
\leq \mathbf{E} f(X)
= \lambda f(a) + (1 - \lambda) f(b),
$$
which is the condition for $f$ to be convex

This is the proof for the convexity for functions, but the main points are just the same.
The definition of "convex" is just the "weakest" version of Jensen's inequality.
Remind that, a mapping $f:V\text{(a convex space)}\to \mathbb R$ is called "convex" (in some books, "concave") if $\forall a,b\in V,\forall t\in ]0,1[, f(ta+(1-t)b) \le tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$.

What if your book define "convex" as "For $f:U\text{(an interval on }\mathbb R\text{)}\ \to \mathbb R$ of class $\mathcal C^2$, we say $f$ is convex iff $\forall x\in U, f''(x)\ge 0$"?
Consider $I=\{x\in U: f''(x)<0\}$. Since $f''$ is continuous, $I$ should be open. If $I=\varnothing$, then $f$ is already convex. Otherwise, let $[t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon]\subseteq I$. Since $\exists \xi \in [t,t+\epsilon], f(t+\epsilon)=f(t)+\epsilon f'(t)+0.5\epsilon^2 f''(\xi)$ (Taylor-Lagrange) and $\exists \psi \in [t-\epsilon,t], f(t-\epsilon)=f(t)-\epsilon f'(t)+0.5\epsilon^2 f''(\psi)$, we can find out that, $0.5f(t-\epsilon)+0.5 f(t+\epsilon) =f(t) +0.25\epsilon^2 (f''(\xi)+f''(\psi)) < f(t)$, contradicting to Jensen's inequality or the first definition.
